# Cursor Position in RichTextEditor

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, smartgwt

is there any way to find the cursor position in RichTextEditor (SmartGWT) in order to add the widgets I'm creating in the appropriate position?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Widgets? What type? Are they added inside the text of the RichTextEditor? Or at the controls layout?

Comment: Various widgets, the main problem is how to find the cursor position in RichTextEditor, in order to add them inside the text. I think that the only way is using JSNI but I'm still trying to find how to do that. Thank you

Comment: Based on this example http://demo.vishalon.net/getset.htm          I created a native method: public native void doGetCaretPosition () /*-{     and I'm trying to get the ctrl in this way: ctrl = $doc.getElementById("get");  but crtl is null. Do you know how to get the RichTextEdiotr in order to run the method? Thank you!!!

Comment: If you check the showcase example you will notice that the RitchTextEditor is not made by a TextArea, so your example will not work. I am afraid there is no such possibility - I mean to retrieve the cursor position. Maybe you want to look into drag and drop handlers.

Comment: Excuse me gpapaz I'm not sure I understand you. What do you mean by drag and drop handlers? Thank you re file.

Comment: Just call the addDropHandler() method to your RitchTextEditor and implement the related handler. The event that triggers it will provide x and y, and assuming you already have managed to put inside the edit area of the RitchTextEditor your widget, you will not event need them to point where your widget shall be "embedded". I just fill you try to achieve something this widget was not designed for, though.