# Insert text at cursor position failing on blank lines

Tags: javascript, gwt

I'm using this native javascript method in GWT to insert text at the cursor position of a RichTextArea.  It works sometimes but often gives me this error message: "refNode.insertData is not a function.  It seems to happen whenever the cursor is on a blank line.

```
public native void insertText(String text, int pos) /*-{
    var elem = this.@com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject::getElement()();
    var refNode = elem.contentWindow.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer;
    refNode.insertData(pos, text);
}-*/;
```

So I need to debug this javascript and don't know where to begin.  I know very little about javascript and only got this method I'm using off a stack [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818520/inserthtml-for-gwt-richtextarea-without-exiting-formatting).  I'm getting the cursor position from another native method I copied from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491259/cursor-position-in-richtexteditor).

I read that this error is because refNode isn't the correct type of object.  I figured somebody would know what type of object it actually is and can help me handle this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have this working I think.  I changed Matthew's answer a bit and it seems to work in all my tests.  When refNode equals Element type, I guess the pos value was always the index of the child node element where I needed to insert before.

```
public native void insertText(String text, int pos) /*-{
    var elem = this.@com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject::getElement()();
    var refNode = elem.contentWindow.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer;

    if (refNode.nodeType == 1) {
        var newTextNode = document.createTextNode(text);
        refNode.insertBefore(newTextNode, refNode.childNodes[pos]);
    } else {
        refNode.insertData(pos, text);
    }
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the problem is the refNode is not the correct type.  One possible solution is to check the type of refNode, and if it is not of type TEXT_NODE, create a text node and add it to refData.  The code would look something like:

```
public native void insertText(String text, int pos) /*-{
    var elem = this.@com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject::getElement()();
    var refNode = elem.contentWindow.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer;
    if(refNode.nodeType == 3){
        var newTxtNode = document.createTextNode(text);
        refNode.appendChild(newTxtNode);
    } else {
        refNode.insertData(pos, text);
    }
}-*/;
```

The nodeType can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_nodetype.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This isn't working correctly though.  I'm outputting the node type in an alert.  When the cursor is on text lines I get nodeType = 3, this is what's normally working.  On the blank lines nodeType = 1.  So you might have these reversed.  I tried reversing the two if-else statement blocks and it worked a bit better, only it inserted the text at the end of text area on the nodeType: 1 lines.  I'm a lot closer though thanks.